# How do I get a list of all languages in PHP

Tags: php, locale, intl

I use code that handles a response from a 3rd party API and that response contains some language codes. I'd seen that there seem to be [standards](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php) defining official codes for languages and was wondering if there was any way to access these in PHP.

I know also that some people just use hardcoded [lists](https://gist.github.com/DimazzzZ/4e2a5a6c8c6f67900091) of codes, but I'd prefer to leave maintaining a list to someone else, it's not every day that a new language will be added but it [does happen](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_changes.php)

My question is how can I get a list of locale and languages in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the PHP extension `intl` includes some classes to deal with locales, but it takes a bit of playing around to get what I wanted.

The documentation for the intl extension is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php). For me installing it was as simple as running

`sudo apt install php8.0-intl`

Then to show how to get the different locales, codes and languages I used the following code:

```
$locales = ResourceBundle::getLocales('');
printf('Found %d locales like %s', count($locales), implode(',', array_slice($locales, 0, 5)));
echo PHP_EOL;

$languageCodes = array_unique(array_map(fn ($locale) => Locale::getPrimaryLanguage($locale), $locales));
printf('Found %d language codes like %s', count($languageCodes), implode(',', array_slice($languageCodes, 0, 5)));
echo PHP_EOL;

$languages = array_unique(array_map(fn ($code) => Locale::getDisplayName($code), $languageCodes));
printf('Found %d languages like %s', count($languages), implode(',', array_slice($languages, 0, 5)));
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Which, at the time of running, produces:

```
Found 751 locales like af,af_NA,af_ZA,agq,agq_CM
Found 204 language codes like af,agq,ak,am,ar
Found 204 languages like Afrikaans,Aghem,Akan,Amharic,Arabic
```